# How To Start App-Switcher from First Window on Desktop?

Tags: application-switcher

[App-switcher starting from the second window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aA3qy.jpg)

While on Desktop, app-switcher skips the first window (google chrome in the picture above for example). is there a solution to make it start from the first window on Desktop?

Comment: Default is to switch to the last active window first.

Comment: @RoVo but that's certainly not the case for me. it switches to the next window. can you double check?